# Maya 2018, python, move and rotate extracted face

Tags: python, rotation, maya

Trying to write part of the python code in Maya to extract the face from object then move it and rotate it. I tried parameters of polyChipOff itself, tried xform and move and rotate functions. Problem is the same. If rotation is after translation face rotates against the previous position not the current one.

Am I understand some concepts completely wrong?

Code below shows the problem. Simply create a pCube and start the script. From my perspective this code should move face away and then rotate around itself many times. Instead it rotates in a circle with a center in where the face was before move command.

```
from maya import cmds    

face1 = 'pCube1.f[1]'
cmds.select(face1)
cmds.polyChipOff(dup=True)
cmds.move(2, 2, 0, r=True, os=True, dph=True)
cmds.rotate(0,0,10, a=True, os=True, dph=True)
for i in range (35):
    cmds.polyChipOff(dup=True)
    cmds.rotate(0,0,10, a=True, os=True, dph=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the face is rotated not around its previous position but around the object pivot (you can try to move the object pivot before executing your script and see the rotation center changes).

If you want another pivot you'll need to specify it as an argument. I am not sure what center you want to rotate the faces around so I've just specified (2, 2, 0):

```
from maya import cmds    

face1 = 'pCube1.f[1]'
cmds.select(face1)
cmds.polyChipOff(duplicate=True)
cmds.move(2, 2, 0, relative=True, objectSpace=True)
rotation_pivot = [2, 2, 0]
cmds.rotate(0, 0, 10, relative=True, pivot=rotation_pivot)
for i in range (35):
    cmds.polyChipOff(duplicate=True)
    cmds.rotate(0, 0, 10, relative=True, pivot=rotation_pivot)
```

Update:
If you need to rotate faces around their own center then it's just componentSpace=True as you've mentioned. So the code looks like this:

```
from maya import cmds    

face1 = 'pCube1.f[1]'
cmds.select(face1)
cmds.polyChipOff(duplicate=True)
cmds.move(2, 2, 0, relative=True, objectSpace=True)
cmds.rotate(0, 0, 10, relative=True, componentSpace=True)
for i in range (35):
    cmds.polyChipOff(duplicate=True)
    cmds.rotate(0, 0, 10, relative=True, componentSpace=True)
```

Comment: True. I tried to use cs as an argument which is for component space. However the problem is all the different move commands (xform, move, polyChipOff) do not move pivot of a face together with face so the component center of rotation stays where it was before. At least that how I understood the behavior of Maya.

Comment: I found part of the solution with new def which aligns pivot to the center of bbx of the face. Now the rotation works as expected but I would still like to understand components transformation concepts better. Movin pivot separately seems odd to me.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I was sure I tried this cs code before and it didn't work. Anyway thank you so much for solution.